# If the desktop shortcut for the daedalus app gets removed, can I make another one? Why is it needed for proper opening of the app?

Tags: daedalus

I tried opening daedalus from the windows 10 taskbar today. This brought up a prompt informing me that this method is an improper way to open it(any explanations why cardano hates windows taskbar would also be appreciated). I know how to make another desktop shortcut in windows, but I was curious to know if there's a 'correct' way of doing this? My solution is to dig around in the file manager taking guesses at which .exe file is the correct one. Is there a faster way of recreating this desktop shortcut? Is there a practical reason (I'm assuming it's a security vulnerability?) for this forced method of opening?

Digging through the web is tough with this problem because most searches only find errors with sync issues rather than local desktop problems.

Answer (score 0):

A best guess for a solution here is to find the daedalus app via start menu "super-key". After opening the app (assuming you let the db sync adequately) and closing, a new desktop shortcut seems to get created for you immediately after closing.

This is incredibly convenient for the troubled user, I have no info to offer on security inquiries or what makes the windows 10 taskbar so improper.